# How can I open my custom URL-s?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ubuntu-16.04, hosts

I'm trying to get my homework done in Ruby on Rails, but I have already faced dozens of problems because of my lack of UBUNTU (16.04.1) knowledge.

I have installed all the required gems and other clients like MySQL2, Apache2 and Puma. Puma is running, I have two standard tables in MySQL, but there is some issue with my Apache2 connection. I can access localhost:3000 (it says: Yay! You are on rails now!), but I just cannot reach my custom URL-s, that are located in the 'hosts' file.

Could any of you help me with getting started? I could blow my top because I have a lot of work to do and I cannot get through the basic steps of installing the environment...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you added them to the routes.rb file?  Are there controllers and views for them already?

Comment: No, I haven't done anything like that. Should I remove the Apache2 module and try reinstalling it? Or which files should I check/edit now?

Comment: It might speed you up to check out a tutorial like Micheal Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial, https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning .  tT sounds like a truly beginner tutorial might really help you with setting up a rails app.  That "yay" view is the default view so you are up and running correctly, but now you have to learn about setting up routes with views and all the stuff that goes with building applications.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely read it soon. BTW I have got a guide that is written by my teacher, but sometimes it is so advanced I have to figure it out what he wants us to do.

Comment: a2ensite
Your choices are: 000-default default-ssl second-hand
Which site(s) do you want to enable (wildcards ok)?
second-hand
Site second-hand already enabled

What shall I do now with this? It say it's been enabled, but I still cannot reach the URL.